# Does the sect Sauram still exist?

Tags: scripture, sects, surya

Does Sauram - the sect of Lord Surya being Supreme Being, still exists? One of my Bengali friends are Saurite. If they are still existing, when did the community got declined? What are their holy books?

Comment: Sauras, Shaktas, Ganapatyas, and Kaumaras all still exist, but in very small numbers. Those sects went into decline for much the same reason philosophical Shaivism went into decline, which is that most adherents of those sects rejected the Vedanta school, so when Vedanta became the dominant school of Hindu philosophy in the centuries following Adi Shankaracharya, those who rejected Vedanta dwindled in numbers. Philosophical Vaishnavas, on the other hand, aligned themselves with the Vedanta school, which is why there are still large numbers of philosophical Vaishnavas to this day (like myself).

Comment: Wikipedia says the Sauras declined in the 12th-13th century.  In any case, their holy books are the Saura Agamas.

Answer (score 4):

Let me add a partial answer because the information i'll be providing is knowledge-worthy.

To be specific,i'm answering this question"**Which Hindu Texts describe Surya as the Supreme Being Or are there any such texts at all**?".This question is relevant here because such texts only will  form the basis of worshiping Surya as the Supreme Deity.

To my knowledge there are two such texts:

1)The [Surya Upanishad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surya_Upanishad),a minor Upanishad allied to  Atharva Veda.

&2)The Bhavisya Purana,one of the 18 major Puranas.

(In what follows,i'll be adding a few verses and an image from the Surya Upanishad,all of which are taken from a book called "Sukta Sangraha".)

Following are few verses from the above mentioned Upanishad praising Surya as the Supreme Brahaman:

> *aum atha sūryātharvāṅgirasam vyā̎khyāsyā̱maḥ | brahmā ṟṣih | gāya̍trī
>   chha̱ndaḥ | ādi̍tyo de̱vatā | haṁsa̍ḥ so̱’ham agni nārāyana yu̍ktam
>   bī̱jam | hrille̍khā śa̱ktiḥ | viyadādi sarga saṁyu̍ktaṁ kī̱lakam |
>   catur-vidha puruṣārtha siddhyarthe jape vi̍niyo̱gaḥ ||*
>   Now   we  shall   expound mantras of  Atharva Veda    in  relation    to  the Sun:    The seer    of  this    Atharva Aṅgirasa
>   mantra    is  Brahma, metre   Gayatri,    Aditya  the deity,  ‘Hamsas so’ham  with    Agni    and Narayana    is  the seed,
>   the   power   is  hrillekha   or  hrim,   the pin is  the power   in  the process of  unfolding   the sky etc.,   the application 
>   is    its use in  repetition  for winning the four    human   goals   (viz.   Dharma, Artha,  Kama    and Mokṣa).
>
> *ṣat-svarārūḍhe̍na bīje̱na ṣaḍa̍ṅgam | ra̱ktāmbu̍ja-saṁsthi̱tam | saptāśva̍- rathi̱nam | hi̍ranya-va̱rṇam | ca̍tur-bhu̱jam |
>   padma-dvayā’bhaya varada ha̱stam kāla-cakra̍ praṇetā̱ram | śrī sūrya
>   nārāya̱ṇam | ya e̍vam ve̱da sa vai brā̎hma̱ṇaḥ ||*
>   The   six limbs   consist of  the seed    with    six vowels  added.  He  indeed  is  a   Brahmana    who thus    knows   the 
>   golden    Surya   Narayana    seated  on  the chariot with    seven   horses, impeller    of  the time-wheel, having  four
>   arms  bearing
>     two lotuses,    the others  bestowing   promise of  refuge  and boon,   set in  the red lotus.
>
> sūrya̍ ā̱tmā jaga̍tas-ta̱sthuṣa̍śca | sūryā̱d vai khalvi̱māni̱
>   bhūtā̍ni̱ jāya̍nte | sūryā̍d ya̱jñah parjanyo̎ ‘nnam ā̱tmā |
>   The   Sun is  the Self    of  the world,  moving  as  well    as  un-moving.  From    Surya   indeed  are these   creature
>   born, so  also    the Yajna   (Sacrifice),    Parjanya    (Rains),    food    and spirit.
>
> *nama ̍ste āditya | tvam-e ̱va pra ̱tyak ṣa ̱m karma ̍ kart āsi | tvam-e ̱va pra ̱tyak ṣa ̱m brahm ā ̍si | tvam-e ̱va pra ̱tyak ṣa ̱m vi
>   ṣnu ̍rasi | tvam-e ̱va pra ̱tyak ṣa ̱m rudro ̍’si | tvam-e ̱va pra
>   ̱tyak ṣa ̱m riga ̍si | tvam-e ̱va pra ̱tyak ṣa ̱m yaju ̍rasi | tvam-e
>   ̱va pra ̱tyak ṣa ̱m s ām ā ̍si | tvam-e ̱va pra ̱tyak ṣa ̱m atha ̍rv
>   āsi | tvam-e ̱va sarva ̍m chhando ̱’si |*
>   I bow to  you Aditya; you are the agent   himself of  work,   the manifest    Brahma, Vishnu, Rudra,
>     Rig,    Yajur,
>   Sama, Atharva Vedas,  as  well    as  all the chandas (Metres).
>
> *ā ̱di ̱ty ād v ā ̍yur j ā ̱yate | ā ̱di ̱ty ād bh ū ̍mir j ā ̱yate | ā ̱di ̱ty ād āpo ̍-j āya ̱nte | ā ̱di ̱ty āj jyoti ̍r j ā ̱yate | ā
>   ̱di ̱ty ād vyoma di śo ̍ j āya ̱nte | ā ̱di ̱ty ād de ̍v ā j āya ̱nte
>   | ā ̱di ̱ty ād ve ̍d ā j āya ̱nte | ā ̱di ̱tyo v ā e ̱ ṣa e ̱tan ma ̱ṇ
>   ḍala ̱ ṁ tapa ̍ti | **a ̱s āv ā ̍di ̱tyo bra ̱hm ā** |*
>   From  Aditya  are born    air,    earth,  water,  fire,   sky,    directions, Devas,  Vedas;  indeed  the Sun gives   warmth  to
>   this  sphere  (Planet)    ;   **that  Sun God is  Brahman**,

[image]

And a few more like:

> All   creatures   are born    of  Surya   and are protected   by  him,    dissolve    in  him –   I   am  Surya   himself.    The divine
>   Savitar   is  our eye and He  is  called  the Parvata because He  indicates   Sacred  timings through His Timeperiods and let Him protect our eyes.

In Bhavisya Purana the Sun God is given over whelming importance & methods of His worship are given in [this](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/bhavishya/bookview.php?chapnum=11) and [this](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/bhavishya/bookview.php?chapnum=12) chapters.

In this [chapter](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/bhavishya/bookview.php?chapnum=15) the Trimurthis(Brahma,Vishnu & Mahesh) eulogises the Virata Rupa of Surya.And Surya's worship as "Omkara" is also described.Here Surya is being described as the Supreme **Para Brahaman**.

> At the beginning of Kalpa, Tri Murthis became ictims of �Ahamkaar�
>   (Self-image) and when a gigantic form of luminosity appeared on the
>   Sky, they were taken aback as to how this huge illumination emerged
>   from! As the Great Light approached and dazzled their vision, the
>   personification of Surya Deva in a �Virat Rupa� (Collosal Form) got
>   materialised, the Tri Murthis and Devaganas greeted it again and again
>   with veneration. Lord Brahma eulogized the Virat Swarupa of Surya Deva
>   as follows:
>
> *Namastey Deva Devesha Sahasra kiranojjvala, Loka Deepa Namastestu Namastey Konavallabha/ Bhaskaraaya Namo nityam Khakholkaya Namo Namah,
>   Vishnavey Kaalachakraaya Somaayaamita tejasey/ Namastey Pancha
>   Kaalaaya Indraaya Vasuretasey, Khagaaya Lokanathaaya Ekachakra
>   rathaayacha/ Jadvitaya Devaaya Shivaayaamita tejasey, Tamoghnaaya
>   Surupaaya tejasaam nidhaye namh/ Arthaya Kamarupaaya Dharmaayaamita
>   tejasey, Mokshaaya Moksha rupaaya Suryaaya Namo Namah/ Krodhalobha
>   viheenaaya lokaanaam sthith hetavey, Shubhaya Shubharupaaya
>   Shubhadaaya Shubhhaatmaney/ Shantaaya Shantarupaaya Shanatayesmaasu
>   vai namah, Namastey Brahmarupaaya Braahmanaaya namo namah/ Brahma
>   DevaayaBrahmarupaya Brahmaney Paramaatmaney, Brahmanye cha prasaadam
>   cha vai kuru Deva Jatpatey/*
>
> (Deva Devesha! Loka Deepa! Kona Vallabha! You are the source of
>   phenominal illumination to the whole World; You are all the Deities
>   like Bhaskara, Vishnu, Kaalachakra, Soma, Kaala, Indra, Vasu, Agni,
>   Khaga, Lokanatha rolled in one as the Ekachakri, bestowing
>   propitiousness and positiveness all over; You are the Embodiment of
>   Dharma, Artha, Kama and Moksha; You are the Personification of
>   Tranquility and Peace, devoid of anger, greed, jealousy and
>   partiality; **You are the Parabrahma Himself!**)

Similarly Vishnu & Shiva also follow  praises Surya with  stutis .Trimurti's worship of Surya Deva also included in that chapter.

Comment: Sauras do not use either the Surya Upanishad or the Bhavishya Purana.  What they use is the Saura Agamas.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan So what?There must be Texts that form the basis of worshipping Surya as the Supreme Deity.Which are those?Just like Devi Bhagawatam tells us Devi is supreme ,Vishnu Shiva Puranas do the same for the respective Deities etc.But may be i should have posted a separate Q&A with these infos.

Comment: "There must be Texts that form the basis of worshipping Surya as the Supreme Deity.Which are those?"  Those are the Saura Agamas.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan there is also a Saura Puraana.